# detect if video is finished with <object> tag

Tags: javascript, object, html5-video

I'm trying to detect if the video is finish who has this form

```
<object id="jp_flash_0" name="jp_flash_0" data="...." type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1" height="1" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; height: 419.625px;">

 <param name="flashvars" value=".....">
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="wmode" value="window">

</object>
```

Anyone have an idea ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `script` to detect when the video has finished:

```
document.getElementById('jp_flash_0').addEventListener('ended',endVideo,false);
function endVideo(e) {
    // Do something after the event
}
```

I hope that my answer helps you!